# Yii2 HTTP session on build server

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, phpunit

I'm attempting to get our PHPunit tests to run on our build server (Windows jenkins server).

They run on my local Ubuntu 16.04 system correctly, but when I get over to the windows build server I'm having some weird session issues.

I have a light wrapper around the Yii2 Session class that we use so that if we change frameworks I only need to update the session calls in one place.

Here's that class:

```
<?php

use \yii\web\Session AS Session;

class SessionHelper {

    public static function get($key, $defaultValue = null) {
        $yiiSession = new Session();
        return $yiiSession->get($key, $defaultValue);
    }

    public static function set($key, $data) {
        $yiiSession = new Session();
        return $yiiSession->set($key, $data);
    }

} //EOF
```

I'm using this SessionHelper for all things session in my app and inside my Test classes.

The issue i'm running into is this: when I call `SessionHelper::set('something', 'something');` from my test case it will correctly set the property into the session. However, the very next time I call `SessionHelper::set('something-different', 'something-different');` it loses all previous session data and only has this new session field.

Is this due to the generation of a "new Session();" in each get/set request? I checked and the session settings are identical between servers and the session_id() is the same all of the time.

Comment: the `new Session()` call wont effect or make any difference although in frontend web application we use `Yii::$app->session` instead of calling like this.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam

For some reason on the build server it's always evaluating to false in Session.php :: getIsActive(); For some reason session_status() is coming back as 1 on every call instead of 2.

Comment: In your console config, you can define a mock session. Read more here : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-codeception/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-reconfiguring-components-for-testing.md

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar - I was actually trying to avoid mocking a session if possible. I figured I could mock SessionHelper calls but I'd rather just run asserts on what I expect to be/not be in session at the end of a test if necessary.

Also, I'm not using CodeCeption to run the unit tests, just using PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase and Mockery. PHPUnit 6.4.4

Comment: $_GET/ $_POST/ $_SESSION / $_COOKIE variables do not exist in CLI PHP. That's why we mock the Yii components that use these globals internally.